# wordpress plugin function error

Tags: wordpress, function

I'm writing a WordPress plugin, but I'm running into a problem...

I wrote a utility file that has a function to check if a user is logged in or not. When I call this function from a file, all is well. If I call it from another file though, I get the following error:

> is_user_logged_in() undefined function...

The page that works is present in the root directory. The page where it doesn't work is located in a different folder (resources/pages/rate_opera.php) The file is included in that page

What should I do?

Comment: Is there any code to show us?

Answer (score 0):

It means the function is undefined.

You're calling it too soon, or from outside of WP.

If the former, call it no earlier than the init hook — and even then, beware, because the user gets logged in early on that hook.

If the latter, there is absolutely zero odds that it'll be defined until you provide the functionality yourself.